# Print Web browser Control in WPF

Tags: wpf, printing, scrollbar, webbrowser-control

In Application window there is scroll view ,
on taking the print out of the window whole scroll view didn't come ,only the window size print is coming ,

I can take the print of scroll view only but is there any way to take the printout of whole scrollview with the window?

> PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
>                   if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
>                   {
>                       // printDialog.PrintVisual(canvas, "Scrollview Description");
>                       printDialog.PrintVisual(this, this.Title);
>                   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didnot get any answer for this question even after editing it, well I look into google several time and after multiple failed attempt finally I got a solution , problem in my code was that ,i used webbrowser control inside scroll view , after reading one solution i remove the scrollview and put code for taking print out of browser control and it works, this is the code i use

```
            mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = webbrwsr.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
            doc.execCommand("Print", true, null);
```

for this i have to include one .NET reference  **Microsoft.mshtml** 

hope this solution will work for any one else facing the same problem.